# replace OR prepend values through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string value in a variable var string which can be

```
var string = '$ <input id='text'>';
```

OR

```
var string = <input id='text'>;
```

I need to replace anything before `<input...` whether it may be `$` or any word. And if nothing is present need to prepend with the new value which is in `var newValue`.

I've tried it as follows but it works fine only if something is present before the input tag.

```
function replaceValue(newVal) {
  amount.html(amount.html().replace(/[^\s]+/, newVal));
}
```

Is there any way I can prepend the value if nothing is present before input tag and restrict anyhow that `<input...` should not be replaced?

Comment: why don't create a ``span`` tag before ``input`` tag..then use js to set value in it?

Comment: no, I can't put only those to single tag, thats the restriction for me, sorry to not mention in the question

Comment: @jitendrapurohit You can try something like this as well: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/15Lrvkb9/)

Comment: Thanks, but I found the best way suggested by @PaulBGD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut off everything before the input and prepend the string you want to replace with.

To fix your code, you'd do:

```
function replaceValue(newVal) {
  amount.html(newVal + amount.html().slice(amount.html().indexOf('<input')));
}
```

and a runnable example without jQuery can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/rffxbfhj/

Comment: Working as expected. Many Thanks!